# Cannot instantiate class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, android-menu, searchview, android-appcompat

Please somebody help me! I trying add appcompat search view to my project. Unsuccessfully. When I change android.support.v7.widget.SearchView to SearchView (API > 10) everything's fine.

This my menu res:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search_view_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    sabd:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    sabd:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

This how I try to use SeachView:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.teach, menu);
        mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchItem.setVisible(true);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchItem);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_view_hint));
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
```

This my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.rgups.time"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light"
        android:name="RTApplication">
        <activity
            android:name="ru.rgups.time.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragments.WelcomeActivity"></activity>
        <service android:name=".spice.SampleSpiceService"></service>
        <activity android:name=".activities.AuthActivity"></activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".activities.HomeWorkActivity"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="ru.rgups.time.receiver.HomeWorkNotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this what I see in logs:

```
   03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798): Cannot instantiate class: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(SupportMenuInflater.java:482)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:441)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:462)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at ru.rgups.time.fragments.TeachersListFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(TeachersListFragment.java:109)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1582)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1956)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:147)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:285)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown>
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:262)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:254)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  ... 31 more
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  ... 39 more
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010069 a=-1}
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
    03-22 21:46:58.583: W/SupportMenuInflater(28798):  ... 42 more
```

Comment: post your `manifest` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in bad v7 support library. After update everything fine.

Comment: Seems that now it has it again, no? I get it on Android L on Nexus 7 from one of the end users.

Comment: Yes, looks like the issue is back with 5.0 update to Support Library

Comment: Try adding this to your proguard: `-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }`

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413938/null-pointer-exception-when-using-searchview-with-appcompat/23934038?s=3

Comment: I don't do any obfuscation and keep getting the issue in debug mode

Answer (score 57):

I had a similar probably that appeared on my release builds but not my debug builds when switching over to the v21 support library. Turned out to be an obfuscation problem, and adding this line to my `proguard-rules.txt` file fixed it:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: where should i add this line?

Comment: If you using  proroguard then you should add into yours proguard rules file. If you not using proguard then this not solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I was using Android Studio and Gradle to build my project. I would like to add a SearchView of v7 compat.

The solution is to change gradle plugin version from 0.9.1 or others to 0.9.0. It is a temporary way I found. It maybe a bug of gradle plugin.
Hope that helps.

```
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.0"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but i'm using Eclipse with Ant.