# Null Pointer exception when using SearchView with AppCompat

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, searchview, android-appcompat

Today I have spent the time to migrate to the AppCompat library. I have setup everything successfully except my SearchView.

Before, it functioned properly, but now I keep getting `nullPointerException` when using the code

`searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));`

I have looked everywhere to try and find a solution for my problem, but I can't find one 
anywhere(The ones I have tried don't work).

Any guidance would be appreciated, ty.

Here is where I am calling:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(searchItem);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));



    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Here is menu XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >>

<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/about"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/rate"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    compat:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView">
</item>
```

Manifest:

> ```
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.stack.overflow.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:launchMode="singleTop"
>         android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
>             android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> ```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.stack.overflow.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:805)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:393)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2913)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 40):

Maybe it's an obfuscation issue...

Try adding  this to your proguard file:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: Yup, thanks. Can't see any official documentation suggesting how you use AppCompat with proguard...

Comment: I came to the same conclusion after half a day of trial and error. This worked for me when migration to the v21 support library.

Comment: can I add this to the proguard-project.txt file or proguard.cfg, or it doesn't matter ?

Comment: it depends on what is the proguard file name you make reference to on your build file.

Answer (score 17):

I had to do 3 things for this to work:

1. I went to my **proguard-android.txt** file found on my machine at **Android/sdk/tools/proguard** and I pasted the following at the bottom of the file:

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

(then I saved the file)

2. In my action_menu.xml file in my project found at **res/menu** I originally had this 
   **android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"**

but I changed it to this

**app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"**
(the only difference being the word **android** and **app**)

So it currently looks like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

3. Then I **cleaned** my project.

I ran it and it finally worked! No more null pointer exception! :)

Comment: You're second point solved my problem! What's the difference between android and app? Why does changing it to app allow it to run properly?

Comment: WayWay, the **android** namespace is used when accessing the Android SDK libraries, and the **app** namespace is used for customizing and backward compatibility. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732512/difference-between-android-and-app-prefix-in-android-xml

Comment: Thank you! I was pounding my head against a wall trying to figure out why no variation of ProGuard changes and importes could make it work without a NullPointer. The `app` namespace was the golden ticket.