# Difference between android: and app: prefix in Android XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the difference and more importantly the necessity of having different prefixes in Andriod view XML?

For example,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/actionToolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentInsetEnd="20dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="20dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
  />
```

Has `contentInsetEnd` for both `android` and `app`.

Comment: Here's useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692233/what-is-the-app-android-xml-namespace

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`android` is usually used for attribute coming from Android SDK itself.

`app` is often used if you are using the support library.

You may also see other namespaces if you are using custom views (of your own or form a library).

Here is some extra information: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand a special case, what is  difference between constraint_layout properties in app namespace (e.g. app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf ) and in card_view namespace (e.g. card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf) for a widget when we use it in cardview?

Answer (score 15):

app namespace is used for custom defined attributes, which are usually defined in `/values/attrs.xml` Here is a sample of such file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SimpleTabIndicator">
        <attr name="numberOfTabs" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="indicatorColor" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And a sample usage would be

```
<com.someapp.demo.SimpleTabIndicator
    android:id="@+id/tabIndicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#26292E"
    app:indicatorColor="#FFFDE992"
    app:numberOfTabs="5"/>
```

Android namespace you use for Android's widgets and UI controls.

Answer (score 11):

`app` is just a namespace for any custom parameters for a custom View.

This can be anything but if you see the root element there's probably a line `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` that assigns the namespace .