# How to make AppCompat toolbar transparent & with zero elevation

Tags: android

I've noticed a lot of material design apps with transparent toolbars with no elevation.

I've managed to make my own toolbar transparent by adding a `background` attribute to the `AppBarLayout`, but I can't remove the shadow by changing the elevation attribute.

Any idea how to remove elevation, or a better way to make the AppCompat toolbar transparent in general? Thanks.

Here is my AppBar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**edit**

Changing `android:elevation` to `app:elevation` just makes the toolbar disappear entirely

Answer (score 4):

**Change**

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

**to**

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

**And**

set `app:navigationIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` as `Toolbar` icon

Comment: Great it worked, but why does the back button disappear? How can I keep it?

Comment: Change your `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. Adding the `android:elevation` attribute just seems to make the toolbar "disappear" in that I observe no up-button, title, or background color.

Comment: android: elevation is used for the stock toolbar, if you are using the toolbar from support library you should use the app prefix. A simple [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=difference+between+android:+and+app:&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjouMOK7oXXAhVFqo8KHSWaBNMQvwUIJCgA&biw=1920&bih=974) gives you this and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732512/difference-between-android-and-app-prefix-in-android-xml) can be useful

Answer (score 0):

- **First** set  `app:elevation="0dp"` in `AppBarLayout`
- **Second** change `AppBarLayout's` theme to `AppTheme.AppBarOverlay`
- **Third** chane the Toolbar's theme to `AppTheme.PopupOverlay`

Here is the example `xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Hope it'll solve your problem.