# Error inflating class ImageView in android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

whenever i hit the imageview i get this error, this happens to me when i switch to test my app on different screen sizes, here is my xml

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/search"/>
```

and here is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ahmed.electionadmin, PID: 30789
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ahmed.electionadmin/com.example.ahmed.electionadmin.Search}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

I have tried so many solutions that asks me to replace src with srccompat and so on, but still is working, ant help would be appreciated

Comment: search icon is a vector drawable or regular png icon?

Comment: is a regular png

Comment: Then use src only and place png in drawable if you have only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `srcCompat` you need to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your **build.gradle** file:

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

Or you can use `src` instead of `srcCompat` to resolve the error.

```
android:src="@drawable/search"
```

Comment: Try to change image and upload it to another folder.

Comment: another folder like what ?

Comment: you can try with mipmap, just only for check

Comment: Great to hear.!

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/search"
```

With:

```
android:src="@drawable/search"
```

> Pay attention, not only `src` with `srcCompat`, also `app` with `android`.

Let me know if it works.

Explanation: You're not using a support library `ImageView`, but a regular one. `app` namespace is usually used for [support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732512/difference-between-android-and-app-prefix-in-android-xml), same as `srcCompat`. So you needed to change those **2 things, not just one.** That's why merely changing the `srcCompat` with `src` yielded no results.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it by uploading my image inside draawable no 24

Comment: Owo congratulation! I already told you to keep image another folder.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing like fitting image to different resolutions , you should have image with different resolutions  like hdpi xhdpi , you you can use vector drawable image

Comment: i copied om image to hdpi ,x ,xxhdpi but still not working