# how to change the color of vector asset in FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, android-button

this is my FloatingActionButton

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_24"
                    android:tint="@color/green"
                    app:fabSize="mini"
                    app:rippleColor="@color/green" />
```

i tried to change color in layout ic_camera_24.xml but it still not work, how can i fix it?

**have a nice day, everyone!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this with **app:srcCompat** and **app:tint**:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_24"
                    app:tint="@color/green"
                    app:fabSize="mini"
                    app:rippleColor="@color/green" />
```

src: https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#mini-fabs

Comment: i did it. thanks so much, but why android: now work, can you explain to me?

Comment: android is usually used for attribute coming from Android SDK itself.
app is often used if you are using the support library.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732512/difference-between-android-and-app-prefix-in-android-xml

Comment: oh. i understood. have a nice day, bro!