# Android Studio: a picture is not displaying in the device but it does in the design

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I've added a sample picture into my app but it doesn't show on the device.
What's wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Sample data (`tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/...`) is for development tools, such as Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry I didn't quite catch you. What is the right code to show up correctly on my device ?

Comment: Use `app:srcCompat` and point to an actual image, such as a drawable resource. Or, use an image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso) and load an image at runtime (e.g., from a URL).

Comment: @CommonsWare When typing `app:` the whispering doesn't offer anything. BTW, what is the difference between `app:` and `android:` headers ?

Comment: @CommonsWare Can I make the picture trasparent so that if it is over a `editarea` the letters are visible ?

Comment: @user2925716 you can make any UI transparent as long as it has an alpha attribute. You can use `imageView.setAlpha(0)` in java or `<ImageView ... android:alpha="0"` in XML

Comment: @user2925716 `app:` and `android:` are called namespaces. `android:` namespace is used for attributes of android SDK itself. refer to this link to learn more: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29732512/8192914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display image, you should use `app:srcCompat` like the following.

```xml
<ImageView
            ...
            ...
            ...
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/resource_name" />
```

`tools:srcCompat` is responsible for showing the files in the preview pane of the IDE. It will not show the image in app.

Another approach to load image would be using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library. You can find how to use them in their respective readme file.