# Studio's demo project fails when extending a Material3 style

Tags: android, android-studio, material-components-android

I've created a dead simple Android Studio's starter project (Basic Activity) and I'm getting linkage errors after adding a simple style file in `res/values/app_styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyFab" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton">
        <item name="iconTint">?attr/colorOnBackground</item>
        <item name="app:fabSize">mini</item>
        <item name="app:tint">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The `app` namespace seems to be unknown to `Android Studio`, every `app:**` item is highlighted in red, and build fails with linkage errors:

```
Android resource linking failed
xxx.myapp.app-mergeDebugResources-43:/values-w600dp-v13/values-w600dp-v13.xml:6: error: style attribute 'app:attr/fabSize' not found.
xxx.myapp.app-mergeDebugResources-43:/values-w600dp-v13/values-w600dp-v13.xml:7: error: style attribute 'app:attr/tint' not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Should I use a different file name/location?

PS: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 on Mac x64, fresh install.

Project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `app` prefix in the attribute name in the `style` definition.

Pleas note that `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` is a child class of `MaterialButton`, rather than `FloatingActionButton`. This means that several attributes which are applicable to `FloatingActionButton` have different naming in `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` or don't exist.

`fabSize` and `tint` don't exist for the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton`.

```
<style name="MyFab" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="iconTint">?attr/colorOnBackground</item>
    <item name="fabSize">mini</item>
    <item name="tint">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for noting the difference, but for example the `app:srcCompat` attribute inside a FAB (icon name) doesn't work as `srcCompat` style item. While all the `android:**` attrs are working as expected. Could you please elaborate more about the "app: vs android:" prefixes?

Comment: @andbi Not all the attributes in the layout can be defined as an item in the style. About the prefix you can check this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732512/difference-between-android-and-app-prefix-in-android-xml