# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView. Similar questions on SO did not solve it

Tags: android, searchview, android-search, inflate-exception, android-searchmanager

Here is an SSCCE. I am using `23.1.1` version of `appcompat_v7` support library. I am running it on a Genymotion emulator with version `23` of Android SDK.

The exact error from the logcat is given at the end.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity_searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SearchView searchView;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_searchView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(((SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE)).getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())); 

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
            String searchQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            performSearch(searchQuery);
        }
    }

    private void performSearch(String searchQuery) {
        textView.setText(searchQuery);
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tests.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="tests.test.module_s.ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_Searchable"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tests.test/tests.test.module_s.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
```

Comment: yeap seems is a problem related to appcompat_v7 library  like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23195932/4848308

Comment: Also, you may take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213746/how-can-i-add-a-searchview-to-my-android-app

Comment: @g2o Mine is the latest support library =(

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi I looked into that. I can't find what they have done which I have not. What do you think am I missing?

Comment: I'm using 23.0.1, and works fine..btw what a beautiful avatar ;)

Comment: @g2o Lemme try using that version of support library. DO you use Android Studio or Eclipse? And thank you.